# BPM Diagram in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am starting my learning in Flutter. I see I can use some ready to use widget such as stepper (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html)

I want to know if it is possible to create a BPM diagram in the app. If so, how could I do it?

I want to create an app that shows a BPMN diagram with diferent colors for each task.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provides us with an example BPMN diagram.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You can see an example of BPMN diagram in the link https://www.conceptdraw.com/solution-park/resource/images/solutions/business_process_diagram/Business-Process-Diagrams-Taxi-Order-Process-BPMN-1.2-Diagram.png

Comment: Instead of a stepper, you could draw all those shapes and lines with https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html